# "Bypass proxy settings for these hosts" works then fails... then works again after toggling Ethernet service

Tags: network, proxy

### Conditions upon boot

1. `privoxy` is installed (I DON'T have it set to start automatically on reboot).
2. Network Settings are set for `privoxy` (please see my Bypass settings):

> Web proxy (HTTP) ON 
>  Server 127.0.0.1 
>  Port 8118
>
> Secure web proxy (HTTPS) ON 
>  Server 127.0.0.1 
>  Port 8118
>
> Bypass proxy settings for these hosts & domains: 
> *local, 169.254/16, 127.0.0.1:8191

3. I have a launch daemon plist that starts a service on `127.0.0.1:8191` called `flaresolverr.py`. **This is the service that runs briefly upon system start then stops - it's supposed to remain running** (it attempts to open Chromium.app to check if its connection is working).

I have set Network proxy settings to allow/bypass 127.0.0.1:8191... I am trying to understand why flaresolverr initially runs, then stops running. I assume it's related to my Network settings having a proxy set without `privoxy` running but why?

### I can get flaresolverr running again in two ways:

1. Of course starting the privoxy service. I start it manually using terminal:

```
/usr/local/opt/privoxy/sbin/privoxy --no-daemon /usr/local/etc/privoxy/config
```

2. In Network Settings > Ethernet: toggle (Deactivate...Activate) my "Ethernet" service. **This works even though privoxy is not running.**

My question... how can I resolve this? What does toggling  (Deactivate and Activate) my Network service "Ethernet" do to allow access to 127.0.0.1:8191 again, and why?

### Additional info

After a restart checking in safari:

> Safari Can't Connect to the Server 
>  Safari can't open the page
> "127.0.0.1:8191" because Safari can't connect to the server
> "127.0.0.1"

Checking in chrome:

> This site can't be reached 
> 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. 
>  Try: 
>  • Checking the connection 
>  • Checking the proxy and the firewall 
>  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Checking in terminal for process reveals some clues

```
13:18:35.658 at iMacEth ~ ps -U 0 | grep -i flaresolverr.py                                            
 3937 ??         0:00.23 /Users/john/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/bin/python /Users/john/GitHub/FlareSolverr/src/flaresolverr.py
```

Now toggle (Deactivate...Activate) Network "Ethernet" service results in a new PID for my the daemon that runs flaresolverr.py and everything is working even without privoxy running...

```
13:18:48.912 at iMacEth ~ ps -U 0 | grep -i flaresolverr.py
 6364 ??         0:00.47 /Users/john/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/bin/python /Users/john/GitHub/FlareSolverr/src/flaresolverr.py
```

Opening 127.0.0.1:8191 in Safari:

```
{"msg": "FlareSolverr is ready!", "version": "3.3.10", "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
```